# ngx-bootstrap typeahead select from ngrx store

Tags: angular9, ngrx-store, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to select my data from ngrx store to pass it to ngx-bootstrap typeahead. My selector from the store is working but i don`t know how i can connect it to the typeahead from ngx.

My code is the following:

```
constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.dataSource = new Observable((observer: Subscriber<string>) => {
      observer.next(this.tourNr);
    }).pipe(
      mergeMap((tourNumber: string) => {
        return this.store.select(getTourByTourNr, { tourNr: tourNumber});
      })
    );
  }
```

I think i am missing a key concept here. What i want to achieve is that the select from the store returns me my actual data but it actually returns the following:

```
Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}
```

So i don`t know how to return the actual data from the store to return it. Maybe someone can push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answers in the docs:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead#async-http-request

Missed it at first. Here my implementation which works:

```
this.dataSource$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      observer.next(this.tourNr);
    }).pipe(
      switchMap((query: string) => {
        if (query) {
          return this.store.select(getTourByTourNr, { tourNr: query }).pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
              console.log(data);
              return data || [];
            }),
            tap(
              () => noop,
              (err) => {
                // in case of http error
                this.errorMessage =
                  (err && err.message) || 'Something goes wrong';
              }
            )
          );
        }

        return of([]);
      })
    );
```